# How to specify gem version to an older version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to use a specific version for gem, as specified by Michael Hartl's ruby on rails tutorial.

I typed in `$ gem update --system 1.8.24`

but i got this output:

`Latest version currently installed. Aborting.`

How do I prevent this command from aborting?  The tutorial notes that I must use the 1.8.24 version.  Thanks!

Comment: what version do you have? type in `gem -v`

Comment: Using `gem -v` showed that i had 1.8.24`.  I didn't realize that I already had the correct version.  The step before was `$ which gem` that yielded this output... 
`/Users/XXXXXXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/gem`.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We can user the following command to update the gem version.

```
     gem update --system -v (version_number)

     using this we can do downgrading the version also.
```

Answer (score 0):

you might face issues when you downgrade from some random version. you have to update your rubygem to the latest version and then use

```
gem update --system version_number
```

To upgrade to the latest version, do

```
gem update --system
```